# Git wrongly believes I am up to date

Tags: git

I've been working on a project between both my laptop and my desktop and using a GitHub repository to sync between them. Last night I pushed my changes from my laptop to GitHub, but this morning when I went to pull them to my desktop git shows that I'm already up to date. Specifically, typing

`git status` shows I have nothing locally to commit and prints:

"On branch main

Your branch is up to date with sync/main"

But looking at the GitHub repository online shows that I definitely have committed multiple things from my laptop since the last commit from my desktop. When I check out the branch's `HEAD` I can see that it has the commit id of the last commit I made from the desktop, including that commit's message.

Any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: "Your branch is up to date with ***sync/main***" are you looking at the right branch on the right GitHub repository? Check which repository `sync` is with `git remote -v`

Comment: Did you `git fetch` first?

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't automatically ask the remote repositories if there's something new.

When you run `git status`, it compares your local branch with the local copy of the remote branch, it doesn't look at the actual remote branch on the remote repository.

You have to run `git fetch` to make your local copy of remote branches up to date.

Note that this happens automatically when you run `git pull` which is basically a `git fetch` followed by a `git merge/rebase`.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't do anything either. The console literally just sits there, stalling. And the weirdest thing is, it only happens with this remote - when I pull from another remote, it works.

Comment: This look's like another issue you can look for on SO. It's most of the time an issue on Windows related to Git credentials.